# OleDB Exception: Could not find installable ISAM

Tags: vb.net, oledb

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Sub connecttodatabase(ByVal fileselected As String)
    Dim databasepassword
    con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = " &     fileselected
    Try
        con.Open()
    Catch e As OleDb.OleDbException
        If e.Message = "Not a valid password." Then
            Console.WriteLine("Database has a password. Please enter password to continue.")
            databasepassword = Console.ReadLine()
            con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = " & fileselected & ";JetOLEDB:Database Password=" & databasepassword & ";"
            con.Open()
        End If
        errorid = 1
    Finally
    End Try
End Sub
```

The error I am encountering occurs at the second con.Open() when I try to connect to a .mdb database file which I created in access, the function correctly tells me I have a password, but then once I enter my password I get the error defined in the title, and I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=YOURPASS;

---

Also, what exception are you getting from the first call to open the db? Maybe it's same problem: the ISAM isn't present. Try reinstalling MDAC:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=78cac895-efc2-4f8e-a9e0-3a1afbd5922e

Comment: The exception I get from the first call is that the password is invalid, so then I prompt the user to enter their password. When I change my connection string to one you suggested I get the following exception instead "Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user.". EDIT: Installing MDAC made no difference.

Comment: After reading a bit, this type of connection string is INCREDIBLY picky, and the slightest typo throws the error that you are getting. Try using this exactly, replacing the paramters with yours (use the exact same case, spacing, etc:)   Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;